# Efficient encoding alternatives for Map<String,String> in Protocol Buffers

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java, grpc-go

I have a protob message to encode key, value string pairs. I was wondering what is the best kind of message layout for the same.

To be more clear, the most basic implementation I used is

```
message KeyValPair{
   string key = 1;
   string val = 2;
}

message KeyValPairSet{
   repeated KeyValPair dict = 1;
}
```

One more alternative is:

```
message KeyValPair{
   map<string,string> dict = 1;
}
```

For my use case, the number of key value pairs is always fixed.
I need to use these messages as part of a gRPC service and want tips for a message format that takes the least time to be parsed as well as transmitted.

My client side is implemented in Java and server side in Go.

Comment: At the wire level, the two things you have suggested are identical. The `map` option probably has better (more specific) handling on most implementations, though.

Answer (score 1):

You say that the number of pairs is fixed. Most times that the *number* of pairs is fixed, it means that the keys are predictable. In *that* case, your best bet would be to be explicit about them, so that you never send the keys (just the tag numbers):

```proto
message MyThing {
    string foo =1;
    string bar = 2;
    // ...
    string blap = 42;
}
```

If the keys are **not** in fact predictable, then: `map<string,string>`. This is identical to your repeate key/value pair message when encoded, but may have more specific / more direct support in many implementations.

You could always combine both, so use a combination of `string` fields for known / predictable keys, and a `map<string, string>` for unknown additional keys.

Comment: So Marc if instead I used repeated strings as a field instead of using separate fields, would it be slower than what you suggest?

Comment: @DaintyLord the question is; are you sending the keys as strings? separate fields: doesn't